# Do I have to offset all screen sizes?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap in my project.

If I have the following code

`<label class="col-xs-offset-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-4 page-label">(dd/mm/yyyy)</label>`

The offset is applied to screen size `sm` as well.  I was under the impression that if I specified where the offset should be applied `col-xs-offset-6` this should only be applied to `xs` only.

if I do the following it works

`<label class="col-xs-offset-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-0 page-label">(dd/mm/yyyy)</label>`

But here I am having an offset of 0 for `sm`

is that correct? or is my thinking not right?

Comment: See https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E029 It's the same for offset classes as it is for other column classes.

Comment: what happens is that all BS column classes cascades up like `col-xs-5` equals to 'col-xs-5 col-sm-5 etc..` same goes for offset,pull,push so to break this cascading u have to use another class to reset it back to what u want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, What you have written in the second piece of code is correct, this is how it should work. It is exactly why you don't have to type `.col-md-4` nor do you have the type `.col-lg-4`.

Comment: I don't have a md or a lg as the sm will just cascade to these

Comment: thats exactly what I answered you. Offsets are cascading as well.